# Mechanical mouse using USB-to-PS/2 Adapter freezes occasionally

Tags: 11.10, usb, mouse, adapter

I am using an AOpen PS/2 mechanical mouse in Ubuntu 11.10 with a [Staples USB-to-PS/2 Adapter](http://www.staples.ca/ENG/Catalog/cat_sku.asp?webid=837523&CatIds=&AffixedCode=WW&=&=&=) with my Intel DP67DE motherboard. The mouse is more comfortable for my hand as it has a lower height than optical mouses. Occasionally the mouse cursor freezes and often I have to unplug it from the USB port and plug it back into another USB port to unfreeze it.

This happens with all the USB ports. I've been using the adapter for a two weeks now and this seems to be happening more often recently. What might be happening and is there anything that can be done to fix this?

The most recent output of `dmesg | grep usb` (earlier lines of output truncated due to space limitations on this posting) :

```
[103776.634621] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 38
[103778.878922] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 39 using ehci_hcd
[103778.987368] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input76
[103778.987485] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.0049: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[103778.995711] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input77
[103778.995841] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[105321.331436] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 39
[105332.265174] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 40 using ehci_hcd
[105332.373105] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input78
[105332.373232] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[105332.381119] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input79
[105332.381257] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004C: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[105473.423859] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 40
[105484.103033] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 41 using ehci_hcd
[105484.211069] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input80
[105484.211184] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004D: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[105484.219340] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input81
[105484.219473] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004E: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
[109165.563603] usb 1-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 41
[109239.381378] usb 1-1.6: new low speed USB device number 42 using ehci_hcd
[109239.489713] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input82
[109239.489828] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.004F: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
[109239.498096] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/input/input83
[109239.498232] generic-usb 0003:0A81:0205.0050: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The freezing was reduced to about once every other day after I opened the mouse and dusted the insides with an artist (acrylic) paint brush. Cleaning the insides was one of the suggestions for this problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/408364/mechanical-mouse-using-usb-to-ps-2-adapter-freezes-occasionally). The paintbrush made it easier to get into the crevices where most of the dust was. I also popped out the circuit board and dusted both sides with the brush. There was just a little bit of dust since it was cleaned from time to time, but the dust could have made more of a difference when using a USB-PS/2 adapter.

Update: Just want to add that I no longer have to "plug it back into another USB port to unfreeze it", I can now plug it back into the same port after I unplug it. Also, sometimes I just have to wait a few seconds to see the mouse movement.